# Sort columns of a matrix in ascending order java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, matrix

> Task is to sort each column of a matrix in an ascending and descending
>   order interchangeably so that for instance first column is sorted in
>   ascending order, second in descending, third in ascending and so on...

**Nothing but plain arrays and matrices can be used, so no Hashmaps,Sets,Lists nor anything similar.**

So far I have this, it is just an idea but I must admit I have stuck here.

```
public class TwoDimArray {

static void enterMatrix(int[][] a, int m, int n) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.println("Enter " + i + " column matrice...\nEnter" + j + " row matrice...");

            a[i][j] = scan.nextInt();

        }

    }
    System.out.println("Final matrix\n");
    printMatrix(a, m, n);
}

static void printMatrix(int[][] a, int m, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.print(a[i][j]);

        }
        System.out.println();

    }

}

static void sortMatriceColumn(int[] a, int n) {
// My idea was to create static method like this and call it for each column 
//while iterating through matrix, so as the method for descending sort, but 
//I am not quite sure of how to 
//implement 
// this to the end

    int temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[i] > a[j]) {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Ascending Order:");
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i] + ",");
    }
    System.out.print(a[n - 1]);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of matrix rows and cols...");
    int rowNum= scan.nextInt();
    int colNum= scan.nextInt();
    int[][] a = new int[rowNum][colNum];
    enterMatrix(a, rowNum, colNum);

}

}
```

EDIT:

Also, I go out of bounds here.

```
   static void sortMatriceColumn(int[][] a, int rowNum, int colNum) 
   {
    //int temp;
    int i,j = 0,k;

    for ( i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
        for ( j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
            for ( k = j + 1 ; k < colNum; k++) {
                if (a[i][j] > a[i][k]) {
                    int temp1= a[i][j]; 
                    a[i][j]=a[i][k];
                    a[i][k]=temp1;



                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(int l11 = 0; l11 < rowNum-1 ; l11++) {
        System.out.print(" " + a[l11][j]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment, and you're about 80% done. Your column sort function is almost a bubble sort, but you're missing the test to see if the array is sorted yet. Next, either implement an ascending and a descending version, or make your sorter able to go forward or backward based on an input parameter.

You can google bubble sort java, or just sort java to see example code and options for sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
       for(j=0;j<m;j++){
           for(k=j;k<m;k++){
               if(a[i][j]>a[i][k]){
                 swap(a[i][j],a[i][k]);
               }
           }
      }
```

For every column i actually did what u did, but i sent the 2 dimensional array to the sorting function, and inside the function i sorted a column and proceeded to the next column.

Your idea was pretty good, but you implemented it for a 1 dimensional, (which actually would have been fine if we need to sort the rows and not the column, cause the rows are indeed an array by themselves, the columns are not).
Hope it helped :)

edit: Your print isn't good, try this:

```
for(int r=0;r<colNum;r++){
    for(int m = 0; m < rowNum ; m++) {
        System.out.print(" " + a[m][r]);
        }
    System.out.println();
}
```

another edit:

static void enterMatrix(int[][] a, int m, int n) {

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

 for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.println("Enter " + i + " column matrice...\nEnter" + j + " row matrice...");

            a[i][j] = scan.nextInt();

        }

    }
    System.out.println("Final matrix\n");
    printMatrix(a, m, n);
}

static void printMatrix(int[][] a, int m, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.print(a[i][j]);

        }
        System.out.println();

    }

}

 static void sortMatriceColumn(int[][] a, int rowNum, int colNum) 
   {
    //int temp;
    int i,j = 0,k;

    for ( i = 0; i < colNum; i++) {
        for ( j = 0; j < rowNum; j++) {
            for ( k = j + 1 ; k < rowNum; k++) {
                if(i%2==0){
                if (a[j][i] > a[k][i]) {
                    int temp1= a[j][i]; 
                    a[j][i]=a[k][i];
                    a[k][i]=temp1;
                }
                }else{
                    if (a[j][i] < a[k][i]) {
                        int temp1= a[j][i]; 
                        a[j][i]=a[k][i];
                        a[k][i]=temp1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(int r=0;r<colNum;r++){
        for(int m = 0; m < rowNum ; m++) {
            System.out.print(" " + a[r][m]);
            }
        System.out.println();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I should use bubble sort in my swap method ?

Comment: Can you help me with this, I get the idea but somehow I am stuck in implementing it.

Comment: @T_dejan 
Hi, i actually did not write it cause you got it in your code, at the sortMatricecolumn function, you did exactly the swap,
you get an integer, let's say temp (as you did in your code), which saves the a[i][j] value, put the a[i][k] value inside a[i][j], and then put temp inside a[i][j]. I'm sorry if it messed, i actually don't know how to submit code in comment on here, but i hope that it is understandable enough. If not, just comment in here. As for the first question, the swap is just between 2 values, and if u combine all the swaps what we are actually doing in selection sort.

Comment: When you find some time you can edit it in your comment, I tried to do it as you said but unsuccesfully.

Comment: `int temp= a[i][j];
a[i][j]=a[i][k];
a[i][k]=temp;`

Comment: that's the code part, did you get it right in your code? If it is still doesn't work maybe the printing is wrong or something. You can send here your code and i'll help you analyze where is the bug

Comment: Take a look at my edit, I still cant get it right, and I still do not know how to implement ascending and descending ordering interchangeably.

Comment: @T_Dejan your print is the problem, have a look at the edit i made to the original answer :D

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to do this interchangeable sorting, as I described in my question.
Do I have to write unique methods for both sorts, can it be done inside the loop I already implemented ?

Comment: @T_Dejan you mean how to sort both columns and rows at the same loop?
if so, you'll have to choose preferable sort, cause if you sort columns first you'll get a different array than if you sort rows first. If you want to sort a 2dimensional array, it's a whole different algorithm... (take all the elements at the array, put them in List, or 1 dimensional array, move on the 2 dimensional array and every time just put the smallest value. For more info on this, just google sort a matrix java)

Comment: Well, task is to sort elements in each column of a matrix so that elements in first column are sorted in ascending order, in second column descending, third ascending ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162656/discussion-between-or251-and-t-dejan).

Comment: hi man
i just posted the most edited code in the comment
pay attention that i changed something at the code, both in print and in the for loops (at the for loops i ordered the rows and not the columns, so i just switched it, and the print printed the matrix print was making the matrix upside down) so i fixed it and posted it
now, for what you asked, i added an if else at the 3rd for loop, which check if we gonna order it by ascending order or descending order. Hope it's helpful, if not, just ask

if you want some code to test this, i have made random matrix generator